# Can Garuda Puranam be read at home?

Tags: scripture, garuda-purana

This question is in reference to the question asked before.

[Why can Garuda Purana be read on specific days only?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2690/)

When I talk to people they mention that the Garuda Puranam should be read at sacred places and not at home. Are these recommendations only out of fear of an inauspicious event or are there direct consequences?

Comment: Yes. It can be read at home. As per the referenced question, this will read when the `occasion of the passing away of someone` and this read by the `priest` at the dead person's home.

Comment: May be it will helpful to you  https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100523222446AABNneD

Comment: Garuda purana can be read like any other purana at home. There is a misconception that it should be read at death of a person only. The segment which is read at the house of dead person is a very small part of the entire Garuda purana. In fact, I think,  there is no mandatory requirement to read that portion or section at some dead person's place.

Answer (score 3):

Garuda Purananam is a great satvika purana about the  glory of  Lord Vishnu. It also contains a lot of theological part and many useful mantras and shlokas. It also contains pretakalpa recited after a death takes place. Nonetheless it can be read or studied  at any time. It will only add to your religious merit(punya).

Answer (score 0):

Garuda Puranam can be read at home. The discussion between Lord Vishnu and Garuda after death how the atma travels thru several difficult places. How a human being should live in this earth when he has ben given opportunity. There are 28 hells described based on the sins committed by a person during his life in earth. Giri publications Tamil version costing Rs.40  can be read. Ir in the google type garuda puranam and youwill get in detail.