# What is the definition of Veda?

Tags: vedas, terminology, meaning

What is the definition of Veda?

I listen to the following two lines but could not understand. And like to know.

> 1. "to know" is Veda. How?
> 2. "Veda is Akhand" what does it mean?

Comment: http://sanskritdictionary.com/veda/221890/1 ;  have a look at [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/774/277) post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word 'Veda' means "knowledge" which is derived from the root 'Vid' which means "to know".

For example,

**Ayurveda**: knowledge (Veda) of longevity

More definitions of Veda can be found in [Rigvedaadi Bhasya Bhumika by Swami Dayananda Saraswati](http://www.vedicgranth.org/home/the-great-authors/maharshi/rigvedaadi-bhasya-bhumika-1878). You may read it on page 30 from [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=dmVkaWNncmFudGgub3JnfHd3d3xneDozZGYyZjZkODlhZTExYjVj) (**Note**: pdf might get downloaded on a few devices)

Answer (score 1):

1. **"to know" is Veda. How?**

Vedas mean “knowledge”. The word ‘Veda’ is derived from the Sanskrit root word ‘vid’ which means knowledge. So, Vedas are nothing but knowledge itself like "Vidya" which also means knowledge. Vedas contain the blue-print of entire creation coded in secret format. In Mahabharata Shanti Parva chapter CCXXXII the illustrious sage Vyasa states the following. This entire creation takes its form and shape from the blue print /seed which are hidden in Vedas. All the great Rishis also have their origin from Vedas.

> “At the outset the Self-born caused those excellent Vedic sounds, that are embodiments of knowledge and that have neither beginning nor end to (spring up and) flow on (from preceptor to disciple). From those sounds have sprung all kinds of actions. The names of the Rishis, all things that have been created, the varieties of form seen in existent things, and the course of actions, have their origin in the Vedas. Indeed, the Supreme Master of all beings, in the beginning, created all things from the words of the Vedas. Truly, the names of the Rishis, and all else that has been created, occur in the Vedas. Upon the expiration of his night (i.e., at the dawn of his day), the uncreate Brahman creates, from prototypes that existed before, all things which are, of course, well-made by Him. In the Vedas hath been indicated the topic of the Soul's Emancipation, along with the ten means constituted by study of the Vedas, adoption of the domestic mode of life, penances, observance of duties common to all the modes of life, sacrifices, performance of all such acts as lead to pure fame, meditation which is of three kinds, and that kind of emancipation which is called success (Siddhi) attainable in this life". (MBH Shanti Parva chapter CCXXXII)

2. **"Veda is akhand" what does it mean?**

The word "akhand" means united or one. So, vedas are actually "one" which was divided into "four" by the sage VedaVyasa (vyäsa means “divide”) in every Dwapar Yuga. Vedavyāsa is in fact a title, assigned to a different person in every Dvāpara Yuga, as described by Vyāsa's father Parāśara in the Viṣṇu purāṇa.:

> Twenty-eight times have the Vedas been arranged by the great Rishis in the Vaivaśvata Manvantara in the Dvāpara age, and consequently eight and twenty Vyāsa have passed away; by whom, in their respective periods, **the Veda has been divided into four.** In the first Dvāpara age the distribution was made by Svayambhu (Brahma) himself; ... I [Parāśara] was the Vyāsa of the twenty-sixth Dvāpara, and was succeeded by Jaratkāru; the Vyāsa of the twenty-eighth, who followed him, was Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana. These are the twenty-eight elder Vyāsas, by whom, in the preceding Dvāpara ages, **the Veda has been divided into four.** In the next Dvāpara, [Aśvatthāma] Drauṇi (the son of Droṇa) will be the Vyāsa, when my son, the Muni Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana, who is the actual (present) Vyāsa, shall cease to be (in that character/title).

Even the 18 Maha Puranas were also written as a single book by the Muni Krishna Dvaipayana but later he divided it into 18 parts to simplify it for the general people like he did with the vedas.

I hope this clarifies your queries.

Answer (score -1):

According to scripture, **the Vedas and their associated parts are a specific race of Suras.** The Rig Veda's real name is Kakṣīvān according to [the Rig Veda](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv04026.htm). Also, Sama is his own son and the son of the Rig Veda according to the [Aitareya Brahmana](https://archive.org/stream/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft_djvu.txt). The Vedas are all Suras according to the [Devi Bhagavata](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57104.html). (I don't believe in boon stories being real, but that would be an unnecessary detail to get wrong)

> HYMN XXVI. Indra.
>
> 1. I WAS aforetime Manu, I was Sūrya: I am the sage Kakṣīvān, holy singer.
>    Kutsa the son of Ārjuni I master. I am the sapient Uśanā behold me.
>
> ...

> First there existed the Rik and the Saman (separate from one an-
> other) ; **sd was the Rik, and the name amai?i.was the Saman**. Sd, which was
> Rik, said to the Saman, '* Let us copulate for begetting children." The
> Saman answered, " No ; for my greatness exceeds (yours •." (Thereupon)
> the Rik became two ; both spoke (to the Saman to the same effect); but
> [ 197 j it did not comply with their request. The Rik became three
> (divided into three) ; all three spoke (to the Saman to the same effect).
> Thus the Saman joined the three Riehas. Thence the Sama singers use
> for their chant three Richas,^^ (that is) they perform their work of chanting
>
> with three Richas, (This is so also in worldly affairs.) For one man
> has manj^ wives (represented by the Richas), but one wife has not many
> husbands at the same time. **From sd and avialt, having joined, sama was
> produced**. Thence it is called sdman.^ He who has such a knowledge
> becomes sdman, i.e., equal, equitous. He who exists and attains to the
> highest rank, is a sdman, whilst they use the word asdmanya, i.e.,
> inequitous, partial, as a term of reproach.

> Sūta said :-- Thus praised by the Vedas with their Aṅgas, with Sāmagānas (the songs from the Sāma Veda), the Nirguṇā Maheśvari Devī Mahāmāyā became pleased. Then the auspicious voice came to them from the Heavens, gladdening all, and pleasing to the ears though no form was seen: “O Suras!

**Thus, the definition of the Vedas is a race of Sura Devas. The texts called Vedas are named after their person of origin.** This kind of takes the mystique away from the Vedas being eternal, as all souls are.

---

Let's complete the real names of the Vedas.

---

Sama Veda's real name is [Saci Paulomi](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10159.htm). You can tell this by the fact the linked sukta of Rig Veda is about the Rig Veda's husband and no one else in particular. Thus, it has to be about Sama Veda, as Rig Veda is married to Sama Veda as discussed earlier and constantly referenced in the Vedas. By the way, this sukta is probably why even sexists have to admit a female wrote part of the Vedas. Technically Rig Veda could be male then and talking about another life/lives, but that just opens a whole can of worms people tend to avoid talking about. The sukta also implies husbands should obey their wives, just as wives obey their husbands.

> HYMN CLIX. Saci Paulomi.
>
> 1. YON Sun hath mounted up, and this my happy fate hate mounted high.
>    I knowing this, as conqueror have won my husband for mine own.
>    2 I am the banner and the head, a mighty arbitress am I:
>    I am victorious, and my Lord shall be submissive to my will.
>    3 My Sons are slayers of the foe, my Daughter is a ruling Queen:
>    I am victorious: o’er my Lord my song of triumph is supreme.
>    4 Oblation, that which Indra gave and thus grew glorious and most high,—
>    This have I offered, O ye Gods, and rid me of each rival wife.
>    5 Destroyer of the rival wife, Sole Spouse, victorious, conqueror,
>    The others' glory have I seized as ’twere the wealth of weaker Dames.
>    6 I have subdued as conqueror these rivals, these my fellow-wives,
>    That I may hold imperial sway over this Hero and the folk.

By the way, [Sama Veda](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sv.htm) has a father, who while assumable as Indra elsewhere, is actually mysteriously unnamed.

> 8. **I from my Father** have received deep knowledge of eternal Law:
>    I was born like unto the Sun.

> XI Indra
>
> 1. In every need, in every fray we call, as friends to succour us,
>    Indra, the mightiest of all.
> 2. I call him, mighty to resist, the hero of our ancient home,
>    **Thee whom my sire invoked of old**.
> 3. If he will hear us, let him come with succour of a thousand kinds,
>    With strength and riches, to our call!

---

Yajur Veda's real name is [triple light](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk18.htm), whatever that is in Sanskrit

> **I am the triple light**, the region's meter: exhaustless heat
> am I, named burnt oblation.

By the way, Yajur Veda has this [weird self testimony](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk08.htm)

> I am in heaven above, on earth beneath it. The intermediate
> region was my father.
> I saw the Sun both from above and under. I am what Gods
> in secret hold the highest.

---

Atharva Veda seems to really be called Atharva, [as there is a character with that name](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/atharvan#purana).

---