# Does even a single sacred scripture sanction or even mention a "patnivrata dharma"?

Tags: vedas, puranas, dharma, women, itihasa

Pativrata dharma is mentioned everywhere. As per this every wife has to obey, worship and serve her husband. She can even be beaten by him if required.

But some feminists and apologists are saying there is **PATNIvrata "dharma"** in Hinduism!! I have found this nowhere even in left-handed path scriptures like Tantra, let alone right-handed scriptures like Vedas, Puranas and Itihasa.

Is such a dharma sanctioned or even mentioned anywhere (even by a villain, uneducated person or foolish character)?

Comment: EkaPatniVrata is there, right?

Comment: few ramacharit manas chaupais are in this direction - http://literature.awgp.org/book/ramacharit_manas_ki_pragatishil_prerana/v1.114

Comment: @YDS that's not a **"dharma"** or way of life like Pati-Vrata. It is just a single a vow. I wanted to know if there is any such **"dharma"** as modern people are saying............ The link you have sent is feminist extremist commentary / personal opinion. There is no mention of such a dharma in any verse. If you have verses which say **patnivrata dharma** please mention. Sacred scripture only. **No feminist commentaries!**

Comment: Just throwing it in that the Vedas imply husbands should do the same https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50151/21895

Comment: So much rudeness in your question, if i were you, I would get rid of them. Please make a proper edit and consider this a warning.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Look at your comment! You're the one being extremely rude... I know you strongly support women's rights/feminism and have tried to ban many times. Go ahead and do so if you want to silence every voice against feminism and support demon Kali of Kaliyuga

Comment: Read this line: ***Is such a dharma sanctioned or even mentioned anywhere (even by a villain, uneducated person or foolish character)?*** Do you think this tone is acceptable? By this you already considered scholars (who would have written in support of your question)a villain, uneducated person or foolish character.

Comment: @Pandya - why was my answer deleted when it clearly mentions fidelity shown by husband towards wife ?

Answer (score 3):

Fidelity in marriage is not a one-way street.

[Manu Smriti Ch.9.101](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu09.htm)

> 'Let mutual fidelity continue until death,' this may be considered as
> the summary of the highest law for husband and wife.

There is another verse I heard in Upanyasam (which I can't find) -

> If a man abandons a wife in her youth without just cause, he is born
> for next 7 births as a woman who gets widowed in her youth.

Even though a man is permitted multiple wives, he has to treat them all with same love/respect. The story of Chandra favoring one of his 27 wives, all of whom were sisters & Daksha Prajapati's daughters, and getting cursed by Daksha is well-known.

How does this not answer the question ? @Pandya ?

Pativrat = fidelity to husband.

Patnivrat = fidelity to wife.

ManuSmriti says - 'show fidelity towards wife'.

Comment: No mention of "patnivrata dharma" .... this is only ek-patni-vrat .... does not answer question

Comment: the word patnivrat may not exist. but the concept does. it does not mean restrict to one-wife. it means treat all wives same.

Comment: That interpretation makes zero sense with four wives of a Brahmana being mentioned later in your link. If you restrict to finances it makes a lot of sense, but everyone knows both of you were not talking about that.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa the story of Chandra getting cursed for favoring one wife, makes a lot of sense. Anyway, Manu Smriti is clear on this topic.