# Where in the Rigveda do I find the hyms dedicated to Brihaspati?

Tags: rig-veda, brihaspati

I know that Brihaspati has 11 hyms dedicated to him in the Rigveda, but where to find them?

Answer (score 2):

Following is the list of some hymns from [Rigveda](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/rigveda/e-text.htm) dedicated to [Brihaspati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E1%B9%9Bhaspati):
(Number denotes `Mandala.Sukta`)

- Mandala 1, Hymn 190 (1.190)
- Mandala 2, Hymns 23 and 24 (2.23,24*)
- Mandala 3, Hymn 62 (3.62*)
- Mandala 4, Hymns 49 and 50 (4.49,50)
- Mandala 6, Hymn 73 (6.73)
- Mandala 7, Hymn 97 (7.97)
- Mandala 10, Hymns 67,68 and 182 (10.67,68,182)

Note: I found that in some hymns he is equated with Indra or Agni. And in some hymns Brihaspati and Brahmanaspati are believed to be the same.