# What is the order of the importance of Hindu texts?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, smriti

In Hinduism, there are many classes of books such as Vedas, Puranas, Smritis etc.,

Suppose any two texts from a different class of books either contradict each other or provides an alternative way of doing the same thing, then what is the order of importance of texts? Does the order of importance is given in scriptures?

Comment: This is already discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16509/which-shastras-are-more-authoritative-the-smritisdharma-shastras-or-the-purana) .. The order is Veda > Smriti> Purana.. Possibly it's a duplicate?

Comment: Yeah, all is there.

Comment: Dont mark your question as duplicate. Just click on it solved my problem. Question will be automatically be closed!

Comment: @Akshay Kumar S okay... Will do accordingly....