# Smriti vs Purana

Tags: scripture, puranas, smriti

[Which Shastras are more authoritative,the Smritis(Dharma Shastras) or the Puranas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16509/which-shastras-are-more-authoritative-the-smritisdharma-shastras-or-the-purana) from here it is clear that smriti is superior than purana and if differences occur then smriti is to be believed . However puranas and itihasa are collectively called 5th veda (mentioned in chandogya upanishad) , and since vedas are superior than smriti , so shouldn't Puranas be superior than smriti ? Has any Acharya or any commentator said anything about this ?

Comment: the puranas are smriti. the vedas are sruti.

Comment: The Smritis all came from the Kalpa Sutras (which are Vedangas). That's why they are less authoritative than only the Vedas but have more authority than the others.

Comment: Smritis and Puranas are different scriptures. Smritis refer to the Dharmashastras/Sutras. If they are the same why would scriptures discuss which one among the two has more authority?@SwamiVishwananda

Comment: @Rickross puranas are called 5th veda , so shouldn't they be superior than dharmashastras ?

Comment: @Raghav I think that is just a praise or eulogy whereas Smritis being essentially part of Vedangas need not be re emphasized in the form of praise as it is a fact. So Smritis have higher scriptural authority. BTW welcome back to the site!

Comment: @Rickross yeah maybe . Thanks , its great to be back , I was busy in my major exams so I deliberately suspended  myself so that I couldn't get distracted , after all this site is great :-) .

Comment: It might be because Puranas have a lot of quotes (others have them but to a lesser extent), which are not authoritative thus on average Puranas go down.