# Are the Itihasa superior to the Puranas?

Tags: scripture, puranas, itihasa

We know the Puranas are less in authority to the Smritis (i.e. Dharma Shastras) as this is according to Vyasa Smriti,Chapter 1,Verse 4. So if Puranas are below Dharma Shastras then where are the Itihasa in authority? I do know they are below the Dharma Shastras but what about it's relation (in authority) with the Puranas?

Comment: Puranas and Itihasas are basically the same type scripture with one recording very ancient history and the other relatively recent history. So they should have similar authority .. In scriptures we also find the word Itihasa-Purana that is they are often mentioned together as one word which possibly shows their sameness.

Comment: @Rickross so if a contradiction arises between Itihasa and Purana what should we do?

Comment: There is a rule given in Devi Bhagavatam on how to reconcile when scriptures having the same authority contradict each other .. I think we have to apply that in such cases.

Comment: @Rickross thanks can I get that particular verse where it is said that?

Comment: Found in this answer (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16510) "And where differences will crop up in the S’rutis themselves, know that Dharma, too, is of two kinds. And where the differences will crop up in the Smritis themselves, consider, then, that different things are aimed at"

Comment: @Rickross thanks