In which scripture it is mentioned that Vedham>Smruthi>Puranam>Sishtacharam>Antaratma Prabodham?
Nowadays many people are relying on their inner conscience or Antaratma Prabodham whenever they want to know if it is Dharmam or Adharmam. But in a Pravachanam I heard we should go by the order in my question. In which scripture is it mentioned?

Related or duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16509/which-shastras-are-more-authoritative-the-smritisdharma-shastras-or-the-purana

@CracklingCyclone it only covers half of my question. I want where it is said Sishtacharam> Antaraatma Prabodham
