# Following the exact Religious facts

Tags: superstitions

Recommended facts  to follow thing like "on Saturday do not cut your hair and nails" there are different people with different views. What is the exact thing which we should refer and follow.

Recently somebody told me that clean shaving is done only when elder brother is passed away, Is it true.

Comment: The esoteric meaning behind this saying is those who are affected by "Sani" or for those whom Sani is malefic, for them Saturday is not recommended. Something bad **may** happen.

Comment: Is there any link which can explain all these following. With the meaning and reason. Or if there any software. Because it depends on person Astro.

Comment: "Is it seriously necessary to follow" ~~  It's better to ask what is recommended & what's not. "Necessary to follow" ~~ this will lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: @sv. Sorry for misinterpretation the whole thing. I just want to know if it recommended then what is the exact fact. How can I reply on such thing.

Comment: Mongrel- People usually follow their local customs and traditions..For ex-In @Tezz's place cutting hair/nails is prohibited on Fridays..in my place no such prohibitions exist unless friday is the birth day of the native..In my place cutting nails and hair are not recommended to be done on saturdays,..So you can follow ur family/local traditions..But there r some elaborate rules laid down in Scriptures on when to do(& when not to do) cutting of nails

Comment: @Rickross I truly accept what you said, but is there any way to know all these costume and traditions as I am willing to follow it. But unfortunately my family was migrated from their native, hence they are unknown with all these. Some people are confusing me with their views.

Comment: Mongrel..I know there are some rules in Scriptures..and i have read them but can't recollect them now..will have to chk ..

Comment: @Mongrel, some such restriction come from *jyotisha* specifically *phalitajyotisha*.

Comment: @VineetMenonis would be great if you can explain, where can I find them. I stay in Mumbai.

Comment: @Mongrel See if [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14976/2995) has answers to your question here, if you agree maybe you can close / delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most popular bengali panchangam is called the "Phool Panjika".The following information are taken from a hard copy of that book.

Shuvaashuva Vara(weekday) Phala for shaving & nail/hair cutting are as follows:

> **Sunday**(if done on)-Loss of wealth(is the result)
>
> **Monday**-Auspicious.
>
> **Tuesday**-Loss of longevity.(AyuhAni)
>
> **Wednesday**-Auspicious.
>
> **Thursday**-Loss of fame.(MAnhAni)
>
> **Friday**-Loss of virility(or of semen).
>
> **Saturday**-Extremely inauspicious,with results like loss of children and
>   wealth.

Note that this is only the VAra Phala .Similarly there will be Tithi and Nakshtra phalas as well but those i have not found in that book.

Personally i follow these restrictions while cutting hair and nails but unable to do so while shaving .:D

Its better for you that you acquire a copy of the Panchangam that your family/region follows.Because, from what i have seen, these customs vary a lot with regions.And usually all Panchanga books have such info.

And,also avoid your janma vAra and janma nakshtra days, as a rule, for these acts.Hope this helps.

Comment: could you tell where in panchangam this info is found ? i'm looking in pambu (vakya) panchangam

Comment: @ram The panchangam that i have is not organized into chapters..this info is found in one arbitrary page..in between the panchangas they provide such useful info ..I have a prayoga book which also has similar info but there the days are changing as per Vedas..For eg one set of inauspicious days for the Rigvedis and another for the Samavedis ..

Answer (score 1):

> Recently somebody told me that clean shaving is done only when elder
>   brother is passed away, Is it true.

The direct answer is NO.

See we all the **enlightened people or Sikh people they usually keep their hairs and beard natural**, when asked they say we do not want to make any changes to the natural body, However **it is obvious that trimmed or clean shave is more hygienic than keep long hairs**.

My point is **why Don't enlightened or sikh people cut their nails?**

Answer may be they will say its not hygienic, but now where does the point goes for keeping the body natural?

Hinduism is a Vast religion, people will tell you a million of things of Don't and Do's.

In Hinduism we are told a lot of things to do and they all are right,
The ultimate Goal is Mukti, for which the base is live in tranquility with a focused mind.

So we should learn that **along with senses and mind, we are given a thing called intellect, we should USE IT**.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @TheDestroyer you are right, but now may be it would be more clear what i want to say ;)