# Depicting Mahabharata (and other scriptures) misleadingly

Tags: mahabharata, sin, interpolation

Most common people don't know Sanskrit, and aren't interested in reading scriptures. They learn Itihasa & Purana from elders or watching TV e.g. B.R.Chopra's Mahabharat, or Ramanand Sagar's Ramayan.

In the past, Itihasas were passed down as a conversation between two rishis, or rishi & disciple (e.g. Bhagavatham - Shuka/Parikishit, then Suta/Rishis. Mahabharat - Valmiki/Ganesha, then Vaishampayana/Janamejaya), and in later years by Acharyas & Upanyasakas.

But recently 2013, some mahanubhavas at star plus came up with NEW Mahabharat (aptly nick-named Megabharat), which is a highly corrupted version, and they try to escape blame simply by putting a disclaimer in beginning as 'fictional' or 'based on true events'.

Are there any ancient anecdotes within Itihasa/Puranas/Vedas of someone misinterpreting  or falsifying scriptures, how to detect it, and what's the punishment if any ? Like a self-certified 'guru' going about dispensing his imagination under the name of shastra ?

Shastra-ninda (blasphemy) is a known sin, but what about Shastra-Parinaama (changing) ? Isn't it worse ?

Comment: I also used to think about the issue of corrupt versions of our Itihaasa, Puraana. It is painful. I think this is a characteristic of 'Kaliyugaa'.

Comment: Related: [What are the valid and foolproof methods of determining whether a certain scripture is interpolated or not?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16234/277)

Comment: @Vineet No need to make it a characteristic of Kaliyuga.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto , why is it not a characteristic of Kaliyuga? I think "propagation of Adharma" is one of its characteristics. Pl. correct me if wrong.

Comment: This is just a propoganda. Its not like Adharma or any issue didn't happen in other Yugas. Btw Kaliyuga gave us many sages like Ramana Maharshi etc. So just don't come up that on your own. :-) @Vineet

Comment: Well, if they don't call it Mahabharata but just Megabharat then it's nothing to do with Mahabharata and thus it's not interpolated.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa, they don't call it Megabharat, that's just the nickname given to it because it resembles mega serials

Comment: @ram Do they call it exactly as "Mahabharata"?

Comment: This is a dup of [Is it a sin to alter or tamper with scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27204)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto , I suggest you to go through "Shrimad Bhagwat" 1st skandha (chapter) wherein King Parikshit's fight with "Kali" and further description of "Kaliyuga" is given. In the same book, characteristics of "Kaliyuga" are given. But out of scope in this comment section. I had expressed my opinion not as a whim, but based on the scripture. There ARE distinct characteristics of each "yuga".