# Can a person of one caste have friends of another caste?

Tags: caste-system

Is this allowed? Do the hindu texts speak anything about this? Can a person of one caste have friends who are of a different caste?

Comment: Of course, they can.

Comment: This question is clearly asking for references from Hindu texts. While it seems to be unacceptable to some emotions, this seems to be a valid question. Note that the OP is not asking about how s/he would react based on the answer. It's like asking if hindu scriptures talk about sati.

Comment: @user1952500 I agree with you. OP's question is valid as he is asking for references from shastras.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury on what basis are you saying this? Please remember here Smritis are higher than the isihasa and puranas in authority.

Comment: @user1952500 i think smritis do not allow such friendship as i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we obey the directives of the scriptures, the upper castes can not mix freely with the lower castes. If they do, there are provisions of even cutting their body parts in the samhitas.

The well-known definition of friend is

> utsave vyasane cha iva durvikshe rastra-viplave/rajadvaare smashaane cha yas tisthati sa bandhavah//
>
> meaning : **He is a friend, who stands (by one's side, in support) in celebration, in adversity, in calamity (like famine), during a scuffle with the enemy and in the royal court (of law?)/at the door of the king and in the funeral yard.**

But lower castes are not allowed to go even to the burning ghat with brahmins, as per Manu-samhita (I quoted some such lines in one answer:[Which smṛtis (dharma śāstras) are to be followed in Kali-yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14976/which-sm%E1%B9%9Btis-dharma-%C5%9B%C4%81stras-are-to-be-followed-in-kali-yuga/32226#32226) ).

Also there are such restrictions as:

> Manu Smriti 8.281-2 A low-caste man who tries to place himself on the same seat with a man of a high caste, shall be branded on his hip and be banished, or (the king) shall cause his buttock to be gashed.
>
> Manu Smriti 5.104 Let him not allow a dead Brahmana to be carried out by a Sudra, while men of the same caste are at hand; for that burnt-offering which is defiled by a Sudra’s touch is detrimental to (the deceased’s passage to) heaven.

So I think it is clear our tradition does not allow making friend from any caste or creed.

**Please remember I am not supporting this.I am just pointing to the injunctions**.

Comment: What/who is a Vandhava? Is it bandhava/baandhava? Bandhu is not friend. In general meaning, he is a relative or well wisher.