# The source of the saying Smruthi changes with time?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, smriti, source

I have heard this so many times by the word of mouth and read it many times, from sources I can't remember, that

> **Shruthi remains constant but Smruthi changes with time.**

What is the source of this? Was it said by Lord Krishna in Bhagavat Gita?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14977/661

Comment: you might look at the meanings of 'sruti' and 'smriti' for a better understanding.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Shruthi are Vedas and Smrutis are Smrutis books of rules amd conduct like that if Lord Manu, Yajnavalkya etc