Is prayaschitta applicable for intentional sin?
In Padma Purana Rama wails that he has intentionally killed a brahmana(ravana)..Sesa deva says You have just killed a wicked person and done his uddhar.but rama says that there is no prayaschitta for intentional sin..Then asks for atonement from Agastya who tells Rama to perform Ashwamedha..
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365319.html
Is it true that intentional sins have no expitiation? Or it is just Rama wailing as a lila?

For unintentionally committing any particular sin the punishment or prayschitta is less harsh when compared to the same sin being committed intentionally..
See the following verses as examples:

Manu Smriti 5.21. Once a year a Brahmana must perform a Krikkhra
penance, in order to atone for unintentionally eating (forbidden food)
but for intentionally (eating forbidden food he must perform the
penances prescribed) specially
9.242. But (men of) other (castes), who have unintentionally committed such crimes, ought to be deprived of their whole property; if (they
committed them) intentionally, they shall be banished.
11.46. A sin unintentionally committed is expiated by the recitation of Vedic texts, but that which (men) in their folly commit
intentionally, by various (special) penances.

Thus in fact one needs to work harder in order to remove sins committed intentionally compared to unintentional sins.

Thanks Sir..Are there anymore verses from mahabharata ramayana etc as Manu Smriti was for Krita yuga..And Ramayana took place in Treta..

According to Parashara Smriti (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14977/4732) Gowtama Dharma Shastra is meant to be followed in Treta and it does talk about the difference between intentional and unintentional sins .. actually all Smritis do that .. @Harsh

8 Thereafter, if someone were to speak
with that man, he should remain standing reciting the Sa¯vitri¯
verse for one night if it was done unintentionally, 9 and for three
nights if it was done intentionally  Gowtama 20.8-9 @Harsh

Thanks for the answers Sir
