# Can a married man wanting to maintain brahmacharya engage in sex for just sensual pleasure instead of progeny?

Tags: sex, brahmacharya

It is known that a married person (grihastha) can practice brahmacharya (by avoiding sex on prohibited days).

It is obviously allowed for him to perform **sexual activity for begetting offspring**.

But my doubt is:

Will his brahmacharya be preserved even if he engages in **sexual activity for sensual pleasure**?

Comment: @commonman Because I red in some puranas that sex is allowed for Brahmachari after marriage. So i get confuse.

Comment: Here we shoud hear from the Smritis as they are the authority in the dos and donts.Tantra is a parallel authority also, but not the puranas.

Comment: @commonman Told in smritis that a person has to do sex only for child after marriage and has to stop then?

Comment: Yes, I think I have read this.Having sex twice a month is allowed only for procreation!

Comment: @hanugm come to chat. Thats correct place to talk. Not here!

Comment: @hanugm, i edited it further for clarification. btw, this also implies another  modern-day question regarding contraceptives - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14179/on-use-of-contraceptive-methods-and-enjoying-sex-life-without-being-kandarpa

Comment: Where did you read this? He should remain celibate.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu which one? It's my doubt whether the couple can perform only for offspring or for enjoyment also.

Comment: @hanugm The question is meaningless now! Its like : can a man wanting to maintain fasting engage in eating food for satisfying hunger ?

Comment: @commonman but it looks so shocking if a person can be Brahmachari after marriage if he engages for offspring only... I hope that sex may be banned based on time, but not a permanent ban...

Comment: @hanugm yadichchanto brahmacharyam charanti..Wishing  whom people practise brahmacharya.. that is Brahman.How can one who is really willing to get permanent bliss want temporary bliss? If he wants, he is still not prepared for absolute Brahmacharya.So why wd such a person be brahmachari at all?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is monogamous and heterosexual.

Comment: Your senses should be controlled is the whole idea. You can be a Brahmachariya but can not possibly realize Brahman

Answer (score 5):

The definition of a *married Brahmachari* is given in the following Yajnavalkya Smriti verse:

> LXXIX.—Sixteen nights are the "" Season " of women. Among these he
>   should approach them during the even nights. Let him avoid the Parvana
>   nights, &c. and the first four nights. **By so doing he would be even a
>   Brahmachari.**—79

On this verse we have the following Mitakasra commentary:

> That period of women, indicative of the state in which they are
>   capable of getting conception, is called *' Season." And that period
>   is " sixteen days and nights," counting from the first day of
>   menstruation. In *' such " a season, and during ** even" i.e., equal
>   (and not odd) nights, *' **he should approach " or go to his wife for
>   the sake of begetting a son.** By specifying "night" day-time has been
>   excluded. " Even nights," being in the plural number, indicates
>   totality taken separately as well as collectively. So that in one
>   season he may go in all even nights which have not been (otherwise)
>   prohibited. By so doing he is even " like a Brahmachari." Therefore,
>   when Brahmacharya (abstention from women) is ordained in Sraddha, &c.
>   **then by going as above, he is not guilty of transgressing the rule of Brahmacharya.**

From the above discussion it does not seem to me that having sex without the intention of begetting progeny will be counted as "Brahmacharya".