# Did Pandavas ever participate in sex only for sensual pleasure?

Tags: pandavas, sex

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34844/can-a-married-man-wanting-to-maintain-brahmacharya-engage-in-sex-for-just-sensua) question contains only for those who want to perform brahmacharya vrat. But I never heard or read that Pandavas are askalitha Brahmachari as Krishna.

Did Pandavas ever do sex just for the sake of sensual pleasures?