# Do any scriptures of Hinduism force people to follow the religion?

Tags: practice

It is generally commented that Hinduism does not force anyone to practice it and accepts people of all faiths unlike many other religions. How far is this true? Are there any scriptures which profess otherwise?

Comment: If Hinduism forced people to follow it, then it would be no different than modern Abrahamic religions.

Comment: The difference between Hinduism and other religions in modern terms, is that accomplished Hindus are called Knowers while nowadays we find no Christian siddhas, at least there is no concept of Sampradaya or Tapasya or Upasana in Abrahamic religions. However in remote places you might just get a Pir baba or a mystical fakir, but even they claim to have obscure origins. The days of Christian and Muslim siddhas are over. Nowadays the clergy is headed by normal people like us, who are verily in Maya and have ahamkara.

Comment: The difference between us and them is that since accomplished Hindus become aware of the universe they lose all egoistic and fanatical tendencies. These knowers have been writing and transmitting the scriptures since times immemorial. So I doubt there is any mention of forceful acceptance.

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar I think you should post this as your answer

Comment: I need scriptural evidences proving my point, or at least some writing of any guru/acharya etc. This is not intended to be an answer and not eligible anyway.

Comment: Related [Why does Hinduism not encourage converting people of other religion?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18240/3500)

Comment: @Arkaprabha Even comments are not for what you did. You almost answered the question. Anything which answers a question should go into answer field and not comments. Comments are only for clarification and suggesting improvement. What you did was answering. Comments shouldn't be used for posting unsourced answers.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma See  [Way to convert an answer to a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74815). Unsourced answers  can be converted to comments if they are useful. Indeed, our policy for deleting unsourced answers use this feature.

Comment: @The That conversion should be made by mods if the answer doesn't meet quality standards.  People are using comments to post unsourced answers. They will have time anyway and flaggers are also enthusiastic about flagging a good answer as VLQ. VLQ definition is something else. Users should give some time for adding references in the answer. Personally, I'm not a fan of converting to comment.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma "That conversion should be made by mods if the answer doesn't meet quality standards". This is same as posting answer when they are not sure of sources. It just doesn't involve Mods and result is same anyway. And you may have different views on this but that shouldn't affect users who are not sure of sources . But in any case it has advantage. Other users can provide sources for user who posted comments and i have myself done the same many times when i saw such comments.

Comment: @The That's why I don't like it. This encourages answering in comments. There are many disadvantages in this. One user just posts unsourced answer and another posts a sourced one later looking at or not looking at  comments. Now users start saying 2nd stole the answer even they didn't. They blame user and that becomes situation bad. 2. Wrong comments can't be corrected. Trying to do that increases noise in the comment section and discussion happens which is against basic rule of SE. Basics shouldn't be damaged. They can't be dv , edited and not indexed in search. Long list.

Comment: Comments are not second class answers. They are comments. There are many posts which say about this and featured question also does that. When we don't encourage something unreliable in answers, why should we do it in comments?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma because there is no other way to answer, and HSE doesn't provide a 'second-class answer' system?........Or is it there, and I was unaware of it?

Comment: Plus, my answer is "based" on Gurus' and acharyas' teachings, but devoid of source. So they are not unreliable fully, only lack the original words. How then, to convey it?

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar Comments are not the way to convey that. Before start typing a comment, read the text it shows on a blank comment. What you did was answering and it should go into answer field. Scriptures are not the only sources. Guru's words are valid as sources. There are many reliable sources and references we can add in answer. You can answer instead.  Not only HSE, there's no such thing on SE network. One thing for sure, comments are not for answering.

Comment: Closely Related or Possibly Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/why-hinduism-does-not-force-any-rules-like-other-religions