# If Lord Krishna is the father and mother of this Universe then why are we so different?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

[In this verse 9.17](http://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/9/verse/16-17) of Bhagwat Gita , God says the following:

> It is I who am the Vedic ritual, I am the sacrifice, and I am the
> oblation offered to the ancestors. I am the medicinal herb, and I am
> the Vedic mantra. I am the clarified butter, I am the fire and the act
> of offering. Of this universe, I am the Father; I am also the Mother,
> the Sustainer, and the Grandsire. I am the purifier, the goal of
> knowledge, the sacred syllable Om. I am the Rig Veda, Sama Veda, and
> the Yajur Veda.

My question is: if Lord is the father and also the mother of this Universe ,which includes us, then why we look so different , speak so different , act so different?

Comment: Even 2 kids of same human parents also look different. :-) The crux here is that, the lord treats everyone as same despite all are different.

Comment: If your mother is same as you father is same as my father is same as my mother then wouldn't you and I look same ? Yes we will.

Comment: All 5 fingers crop up from the same hand. Still they look different, have different functions.

Comment: Krishna is father to everyone by soul, not by body. Body may differ from person to person but soul remains same. Soul is part (ansha) of parbrahma(Krishna) that's why he is Father/Mother to all. In this universe many different bodies can be found like animals, birds, trees, insects and bacteria ect. But their soul remains same, only body is differ. Your body is part(ansha) of your parents that's why you looks like them But your soul is part of Parbrahma.

Comment: To be more clear, by soul I mean aatma. May be I chosed wrong word for aatma.

Comment: @Rishabh is extremely correct.He is not our Biological father that He would have a set of genes, and he would copy two sets of 23 chromosomes and create us. He is beyond this biological thing. He is called Mother and Father in the sense of relationship,not biology(for ex, a child may have some other Biological mother, but the child may see some other woman as being really her mother, as in adoption).So it is relation thing. And in fact, Vishnu does not even have any form. He is Supreme and has no form. He is not dark, nor white, nor red, nor sphere, neither big, neither small, nor any form.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Adopted Mother and Father are the sustainer they are not the Mother and Father. Suppose you are an adopted son. If you ask your adopted mother or father that who are your real parents? Will they say such a relationship does not exist ? No. They will tell you who your real parents are. Therefore when God says he is mother and father of all that means we originate from him. If we originate from him then why are we all so different (from bacteria to humans)? That is my question.

Comment: Our spirit (aatma) is generated from Parbrahma, not our body... You are talking about body which has nothing to do with parbrahma. Is this so tough to understand? Krishna is father to your aatam, not to your body as simple as that.

Comment: Your body is ansha of your worldly parents(coz body generated by parents) that's why your body looks like them BUT you aatma is ansha of Parbrahma(coz aatma generated by Parbrahma) that's why your aatma looks like Parbrahma. I don't think I can make more clear than this ;p

Comment: I understood. Everyone is ansha of same parambrahma. If so why is my atma different from yours? Each one of us have different flavor of atma which makes rich or poor , smart or stupid , fast or slow, good listener or bad listener, and so on ...my question is why are our souls so different if they are coming from same father and mother ?

Comment: All aatmas are same, there is no difference. If from sea we pick 2 drops of water then both drops are differ entities but has exact same qualities. Here sea is Parbrahma and 2 drops are aatma(ansha of parbrama). What ever qualities (smart or stupid , fast or slow etc) you are discribing those are qualities of body, not of aatma. Krishna clearly mentioned in BG that all experience during our life time are experience of body, not of aatma. Whatever joy or grief we feel that feeling use to take by body, not by aatma. Spirit don't have any qualities(gunas) coz he is part of nir-guna ishwar.

Comment: @Rishabh If all atmaas are same then why don't we agree that you and me are the same? Why I spend time watching movies and you praying to God? If all atmaas are same then why do we eat chicken , goat, buffalo ? Why do we make other atmaas suffer ? And finally God gave rise only to my Atma then tell me who gave rise to my body ?  God says "Of this universe, I am the Father; I am also the Mother, the Sustainer, and the Grandsire" He is the originator of Universe and not just Atma. But why are we debating. Why shouldn't we put an answer to the question?

Comment: I already told you whatever experience you are getting (watching movie, eating ect) all those experience is of your body, not of your aatma. If you enjoy watching movie then that feeling of joy is feel by your body (mann which is invisible part of body). Atma can't experience joy or grief. All attraction toward object caused by mann. Read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20598/is-sambhoga-sex-the-need-of-the-body-or-soul-as-per-vedas/20608#20608) to know more and ask if any doubt left after reading this :)

Comment: Why are you taking this literally? Krishna is just using the Gita to put some importance to him just like other gods do in other scriptures. Don't take it literally.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: because God is everything. For example, you have a soul, and it's covering is the body. Similarly, God is the white board on which everything happens; his covering is the rocks, trees, leaves, sky, etc. He is the slate on which all is happening. The matrix is happening on God, in other words, He is supporting all of it. He supports love, hate, peace, war, etc. because he is the slate on which it occurs and he is separate from it and does not interfere in the story He wrote; humans cannot comprehend this; if you try to, you will sink by the weight of the world. As far as father and mother, you can't have one without the other and nothing can be produced without the joining of two or more things; good and bad, man and woman, tall and short, the fire and the sacrifice, the sickness and the medicinal herb, etc. It all goes together.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we are not so different! We ‘appear’different because we tend to identify with our body, our mind and our intelligence as the self! Further ‘endorsed’ by the ahamkara, the false ego, we are indeed but identifying with the proxy of our real self! Once we ‘take’ to the teachings of the Gita et al. and indeed ‘transform’ our rupa from samsara to ‘satchitananda’ we will resemble the Lord in many of His (or Her!)  divine aspects, so said. Do not we speak of a ‘family resemblance’ or indeed the entourage or parivara of the Deva? Hence look within and see for your self, the Self , defined ad- infinitum in all scriptures extant as the eternal atman..the ever ananda! Om Tat Sat!

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. Take a look at [answer] and cite some sources.