# Are there prohibitions regarding reading or hearing Garuda Purana and if yes which Scriptures mention them?

Tags: scripture, puranas, death, garuda-purana

Among the 18 major Puranas one is called the [Garuda Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garuda_Purana).Usually its recited during death rites .

There is also a belief that it should only be recited during death rites and not in normal circumstances i.e  where no death has occurred in a family.

To verify the Scriptural basis of this belief i mailed one very learned(Shastragya) person( with whom i correspond quite often) who is very closely associated with the Kaamakoti.org's activities.

He has written a lot of books,on topics like Upanishads,Smritis,Puranas,Itihasas etc, which are hosted by Kamakoti.

I am giving below the correspondence that i had with him through e-mail:

> **Me**-Dear Sir,
>
> You have written books on every  major Puranas but not any on the
>   Garuda Purana.
>   Does it mean that not everyone is allowed to read or hear it in normal
>   circumstances?**Are there any such prohibitions?**
>
> **Expert**-**yes, [HH Vijyendra Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijayendra_Saraswati_Swamigal) asked me not to translate and
>   concise Garuda purana**

So, to my question "Are there any such prohibitions?" he replied "Yes[there are] and then he said that even Sri Vijyendra Saraswati opposed the idea of making the summary of Garuda Purana publicly available on their site for everybody's perusal.(and this can verified easily by visiting their site as well which provides summaries of all Puranas except the Garuda Purana)

That proves that the belief might not be  just a belief and there are indeed some concerns regarding making Garuda Purana available publicly or on it being read on normal days.

**Questions**

**1) Are there prohibitions regarding reading or hearing Garuda Purana and if yes which Scriptures mention them?**

**2) Or are there some chapters in the Purana that make it unfit to be recited by everyone & on any occasions?If yes,which are those chapters?**

Comment: Did you ask Kamakoti people about scriptural reference for this practice?

Comment: @TheDestroyer No i did not want to bother him with more questions ..primarily becoz if i did so it wud have been like questioning the authority of Sri Vijendra Saraswati...Once Sri Saraswati has said so we must believe him..& secondarily becoz he remains very busy and he is elderly too..The work of finding the actual Scriptural reference can now be done on sites like this..

Comment: I don't think he would be bothered by that. He would have easily said the sources unlike us, as they are experts in the subject.

Comment: @Rickross How is this question not a duplicate of [other question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2690/2995)? Both seem same to me.

Comment: There's a program called Dharma Sandhehalu in Telugu channel Bhakti TV. Many knowledgeable Pundits from Telugu states provide answers to questions. I saw opinions of 3 pundits and none of them say this is correct. One Pundit says "Puranas can be read at any time without any exceptions" (quotes Sanskrit verse written by Vyasa).

Comment: @TheDestroyer Did he say about all Puranas ? Here the discussion is about GP only..Also i have in my favor Sri Sararswati's objections ..also u can verify that kamakoti has provided summary of all major puranas except possibly GP..

Comment: @Rickross Yes. 3 of them said all Puranas. I don't know where the exact verse is mentioned.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Ok then try and see if u can get that verse and post it here as an answer..We will see then..

Comment: @Rickross Saw your edits. Still not convinced. Your title is very generic. Also, when you say "that is why Sri Vijayendra Saraswati had objections in putting a translation of the said Purana on the Kamakoti.org" - now that is not a fact, you are just guessing. Now if the person who e-mailed you says "I did not translate GP because XYZ scripture says not to read or translate" then you have a very valid question. But the person only said: "HH Vijayendra Saraswati asked me not to translate and concise Garuda Purana" -- from that one line you cannot say "there must be scriptural injunction". JMHO.