# Why one shouldn't read or watch 'Mahabharata' in the form of book or teleserial?

Tags: mahabharata

We are told right from childhood that one shouldn't read or watch **'Mahabharata'** in the form of book or teleserial, as it might cause fights among the family members.

Is this right & applicable today as well ?

Comment: "it might cause fights among the family members...Is this right & applicable today as well?" - It's pure superstition meant to scare people and serves no purpose in today's world. There is a [similar rumor on Garuda Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2690) - they say you should only read it when someone dies, again no basis, no logic, just one more irrational belief.

Comment: I feel the same and I also believe that in present age with advanced tech. & internet, there are already such mediums which promotes negativity and ill emotions.

Gone are the times when humans have no access to internet and thus the book was considered not good to keep among the family.